# Const placement to stop editing of pointer data with boost shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, constants

So Wikipedia tells me (correctly i believe) that to stop the editing of the data of a pointer and the pointer itself that I should do this:

```
void function(int const * const var)
```

Is this the same as this function:

```
void function(const int * const var)
```

And in that case why is it allowed? Because I know that you cant do this because of duplicate const compile error:

```
void function(const int const * const var)
```

I essentially want to do the same with a boost pointer. Would I do this:

```
void function(const boost::shared_ptr<int> const var)
```

And how would this affect my ability to loop over say a shared pointer to a vector? Could I do this with that guard:

```
void function(const boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> const var)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < var->size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << var[i];
    }
}
```

**Adition: After Brian's answer**

So if I create a a pointer like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<vector<int>> lala
```

And i use it in this function:

```
function (const boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<const int>> var)
```

will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `int const * const var` is the same as `const int * const var`. You can put `const` before or after the type it modifies, for "historical reasons". See http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#constplacement

For a smart pointer object, you indeed cannot do

```
const boost::shared_ptr<int> const
```

because both `const`s modify the same type. Instead, you want

```
const boost::shared_ptr<const int>
```

The first `const` prevents the pointer itself from being modified (*i.e.*, reassigned to point to another `int`) and the `const` in the template parameter tells the object's `operator*` to return a `const int&`, which prevents modification of the `int` pointed to.

This does not prevent iteration over a vector or other container in the manner you have described, for the same reason why you can still iterate over a `const` vector normally.

**Edit in response to question edit**:

This works:

```
void f(const boost::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int> > var);
// ...
boost::shared_ptr<vector<int> > lala;
f(lala);
```

The first `const` in the parameter doesn't affect parameter passing at all; it only tells the function itself not to modify the parameter. The reason why we can add a `const` in the template parameter is that a `boost::shared_ptr<T>` can be initialized from `boost:shared_ptr<U>` where `T` and `U` are not necessarily the same type, as long as `U*` is implicitly convertible to `T*`. If `T` is the same as `U` except with greater cv-qualification, as in this case, the conversion is possible.

Don't do `std::vector<const int>`. I'm fairly sure that's not legal. (At least I've gotten multiple screens of compilation errors every time I've tried it.)

Comment: Nice historical reference.

Comment: So if i declare the `boost_ptr` that i am passing into the function like this: `boost::shared_ptr<vector<int>> lala` will i be able to pass it into the function. What i want is for this function to not be able to change the values or the pointer but other functions might.

Comment: @Ben: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

const before or after the int is the same so:

```
int const * var
```

and

```
const int * var
```

are the same and mean the value pointed to cannot be changed

const after the * means that the pointer cannot be reassigned.

If I understand correctly, you'd like to make the vector const. If that's the case the syntax would be this:

```
void function(const boost::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int>>& var)
```

The smart pointer is passed by const reference because it's cheaper than passing the smart pointer by value and has the same effect. The object pointed to by the smart pointer is immutable by declaring the type it points to as const.

Answer (score 1):

#### Before, or after?

The below two lines are semantically equivalent, both declare a pointer which value cannot be changed, that refers to an `int` that cannot be changed.

```
int const * const p1 = ...; 
const int * const p2 = ...;
```

The *const* keyword binds to whatever is directly to the left, *unless* there's nothing to the left, in which case it will hug whatever is on the right.

---

#### The more `const`, the better?

```
 typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> shared_int_ptr;

 const shared_int_ptr const p3; // ill-formed
```

The above *typedef* is provided to make it easier to see that `boost::shared_ptr<int>` is a single name, and therefore we cannot add `const` on both sides; duplicate *consts* are (as you mentioned) not legal C++.

Just applying one wouldn't be sufficient either, since that would make the wrapper *const*, but not the internal object that it is referring to (the *int*).

Previously we wrote that `boost::shared_ptr` should wrap around an `int`, but since we want to make the wrapped type `const`, well.. let's wrap the *shared_ptr* around what we want:

```
void func (const boost::shared_ptr<const int> foo);
```

In the above `func` is not able to modify `foo`, nor the `int` referred to by `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly reasoned that `const shared_ptr<Foo>` doesn't make Foo a const object. This "loophole" is described on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#Loopholes_to_const-correctness). Instead, you need to change the pointer type stored by boost::shared_ptr. This can be done in the template argument itself:

`void function(const boost::shared_ptr<const std::vector<int>>& var)`

boost::shared_ptr has a copy-constructor that allows for a const-type to be copied from a non-const-type. The opposite should not be possible.